# Updating the FAQ (early)

Tags: discussion

It's probably too soon to talk about updating the FAQ completely, but is it possible for us to at least provide a link to the meta questions indicating what's on and off topic?

https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic

Or would it be inappropriate to do so? Perhaps we could write an interim summary of what's on and off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its important to emphasise in the FAQ that the concept of on/off topic is important in this type of Q&A site. Things are still under discussion as to what is ok and what is not, so for now best thing to do is as you suggest, link to these discussions. There are no clear answers, but hopefully it will be enough to get people to pause & think before asking.

Comment: Do we have anyone who can do that? I assume this will have to wait until we elect pro tem moderators.

Comment: @neilfein: looks like you me and Dustin have the power to edit the FAQ now...  Think one of us should update it with a link to http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic ?